# android InputFilter maximumLength toast

Tags: android, toast, input-filter

I have editText field and I added InputFilter. This is the code:

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
InputFilter maxLengthFilter = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10);
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{
        maxLengthFilter });
```

This code doesn't allow to create more than 10 characters, but when my app generates 11 character it crashes, instead i want to make a toast that the maximum has achieved.

Does anyone know how to add this toast?

Logcat :

```
07-22 12:47:59.339: I/Choreographer(836): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-22 12:48:09.239: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(836): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-22 16:23:10.009: D/dalvikvm(836): GC_CONCURRENT freed 201K, 3% free 8203K/8455K, paused 80ms+14ms, total 202ms
07-22 16:23:23.529: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(836): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-22 16:23:31.279: E/Trace(897): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-22 16:23:31.789: I/System.out(897): lightgreen
07-22 16:23:32.389: D/gralloc_goldfish(897): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-22 16:23:39.589: D/AndroidRuntime(897): Shutting down VM
07-22 16:23:39.589: W/dalvikvm(897): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  ... 11 more
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (11 ... 11) ends beyond length 10
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1016)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:592)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:94)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at home.jmstudios.calc.Main.addText(Main.java:330)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at home.jmstudios.calc.Main.onClickListener1(Main.java:432)
07-22 16:23:39.629: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  ... 14 more
07-22 16:23:41.608: I/Process(897): Sending signal. PID: 897 SIG: 9
07-22 17:14:42.339: E/Trace(1044): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-22 17:14:42.929: I/System.out(1044): lightgreen
07-22 17:14:43.510: D/gralloc_goldfish(1044): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-22 17:14:48.419: D/AndroidRuntime(1044): Shutting down VM
07-22 17:14:48.419: W/dalvikvm(1044): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     ... 11 more
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (11 ... 11) ends beyond length 10
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1016)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:592)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:94)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at home.jmstudios.calc.Main.addText(Main.java:343)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     at home.jmstudios.calc.Main.onClickListener8(Main.java:508)
07-22 17:14:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1044):     ... 14 more
07-22 17:14:48.769: D/dalvikvm(1044): GC_CONCURRENT freed 192K, 3% free 8211K/8455K, paused 76ms+28ms, total 281ms
```

Comment: Can you add the logcat please

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the edit text in XML:

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

If the toast is super important you can just check the length of the edit text and when it equals 10 send the toast.

Of if you need the toasts (mmm toast)

You can use the .length property of every the string to get the edit text string length

```
final length = editText.getText().length();
```

then test it.

```
final length = editText.getText().length();
if(length > 10)
{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, //or whatever activity you toast
        "Max Characters Achieved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I did just what you suggested in Java activity my question is how can i add this toast